# Why can't the w3c validator load Perl's SGML::Parser::OpenSP?

Tags: php, perl, apache, w3c

I have installed W3C validator locally on Windows, following [their instructions](http://validator.w3.org/docs/install_win.html).

I am getting this error while validating a site:

> Can't locate loadable object for module SGML::Parser::OpenSP in @INC (@INC contains: C:/www/perl/site/lib C:/www/perl/lib .) at C:/www/validator/httpd/cgi-bin/check line 60
>   Compilation failed in require at C:/www/validator/httpd/cgi-bin/check line 60.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/www/validator/httpd/cgi-bin/check line 60.

I am using [SGML::Parser::OpenSP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SGML-Parser-OpenSP) 0.991 module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error looks like [SGML::Parser::OpenSP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SGML-Parser-OpenSP) is looking for something it needs. The module depends on the [OpenSP library v1.5.2 or later](http://openjade.sf.net/) according to its README file. Did you install that?