# SGML::Parser::OpenSP - Open Jade Nightmare

Tags: iis, w3c, w3c-validation

I'm trying to install the W3C validator (local copy) and I have managed to install Perl and all its modules except for `SGML::Parser::OpenSP`

The problem I'm running into is that apparently I need OpenSP or OpenJade, and I've downloaded the source for both of those, but i cant compile it.

I'm using

> Windows 7 x64
>
> IIS 7.5
>
> Active Perl 5.16.1
>
> Installing modules via CPAN

**What am I asking for help on?**

How/Where can i get a working compilation of OpenSP or OpenJade, or install SGML without it?

(Edit)

The guide i was using : http://validator.w3.org/docs/install_win.html

Your help would be appreciated more than you may think :)

Comment: somewhat related to this post aswell, same problem, no answer : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685468/why-cant-the-w3c-validator-load-perls-sgmlparseropensp?rq=1)

Comment: And this one  [Topic 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856778/sgmlparseropensp-doesnt-work-when-installing-local-w3c-validator-on-windows?rq=1)

Comment: Is there any way you could run this on a different OS, maybe in a VM? It would be easier in most linux distributions. Debian/Ubuntu has a libsgml-parser-opensp-perl package for example.

Comment: I suppose I Could, however eventualy i would like to install this on Windows server 2008 R2, and if i cant get it working windows 7, i dont want to clog the server. At production level a VM would not be handy, thus me asking how to get this work. In the guide from W3C, the windows guide has had to do this on windows, so there must be a sollution. However seeing how many similar questions have been asked, its not all that simple, once i get a proper answer, Ill do the effort of writing a proper guide.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the binaries are available here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/openjade/files/latest/download?source=files

There is an onsgmls.exe in the OpenSP-1.5.2-wn32.zip package.